# Mapping an enum to String in R2DBC

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc

Using JPA, I can have a member within my entity that maps an `enum` and persists it as a String:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyEnum myEnum;
```

As JPA doesn't work with R2DBC, I can't use that nice shorthand. Is there a clean way of effecting this mapping when using R2DBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will map enum to string and vice versa by default without the annotation.